# jeasyui apply CSS style in edit mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-easyui

The example given by jeasyui webpage always show styler during retrieval of datagrid records.
Meaning that the jEasyUi apply the style when the datagrid is loaded. For example:
http://jeasyui.com/demo/main/index.php?plugin=DataGrid in *DataGrid Cell Style* link.
How to apply the style during editing mode?

```
<th data-options="field:'qty',width:100, 
   styler:cellStyler, 
   editor: { type:'numberbox', 
   options: 
      { required:'true', precision:2, onChange:onChangeQty }
   }">
Qty</th>
```

The cellStyler took effect only during the datagrid loaded,

```
function cellStyler(value,row,index){
    alert(value);
    if (value < 30){
        return 'background-color:#ffee00;color:red;';
    }
}
```

so I add in the onChange to do the validation

```
function onChangeQty(newValue, oldValue) 
{
    var qohField = $("#dg-form").datagrid("getEditor", {index:editIndex,field:"qoh"});
    if (eval($(qohField.target).numberbox('getValue')) < eval(newValue)) {
        console.log($(qohField.target).numberbox('getValue'));
    }
}
```

but then, how can the onChange change the style color of the cell background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to add this code to your  `onChangeQty` function

```
.....
var dg = $('#dg-form');
var col = dg.datagrid('getColumnOption','qty');
.....

.....
col.styler = function(){
  return 'background-color:#ffee00;color:red;';
};

dg.datagrid('refreshRow',editIndex);
```

this is not tested,for your more information I found the solution for the others [here](http://www.jeasyui.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=g7cbe6o9egb3065ua71enqvgr0&topic=1747.msg3840#msg3840)